# What does the "5.0mm" mean on this motor's nameplate?

Tags: motor, dc-motor

I am testing a motor, but I am confused about the nameplate of the motor. Can anyone tell me the meaning of 5.0 mm on the motor nameplate?

[image: photo of motor]

Comment: Shaft diameter?

Comment: no sir. I checked it

Comment: Your question would be greatly enhanced by a picture of the nameplate and a link to the manufacturer's website (if available)

Comment: @YasirBilal - Hi, I have done a "rollback" to undo your last edit, where you removed the image of the motor's label. You didn't give any reason for that change and it's a very relevant piece of information, so please leave it in the question. Thanks.

Comment: @YasirBilal - Hi, Yet again, you removed the image of the motor's label in an edit. So, yet again, I have performed a "rollback" to undo that edit. Why do you keep doing this? Thanks.

Comment: One manufacturer's website shows a 5.0 mm shaft diameter for the RS-55SH motor. https://leisonmotor.en.made-in-china.com/product/qBNJFuEjbLrQ/China-RS-555sh-6V-12V-24V-High-Speed-DC-Motor-Vacuum-Cleaner-Motor-Car-Brake-Motor.html However, I have several RS-555 motors and they have 3.2 mm shafts. Actually the drawing shows diameter as 3.175 mm.

Answer (score 4):

5.0 mm mentioned on the motor nameplate could be the maximum depth available for the mounting screws.

Screw entry to a depth greater than 5.00mm could damage the motor.

Comment: Quite possibly but it would seem actively unhelpful of the manufacturer not to spell that out, or even put it in the context of the fixing screw diameter/thread.

Comment: @Frog I agree with your comments BUT also suspect that's the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

On the [manufacturer's product page](http://en.chengfang-motor.com/prod_view.aspx?TypeId=79&Id=214&FId=t3:79:3) there is a diagram with dimensions.

There are two dimensions with no values given, just letters A and B. Both of these dimensions include the motor shaft. This could indicate that the shaft length can be different for different applications. There is mention on the page of custom shaft options.
It would then make sense that they may indicate the shaft length on the label and that may be what the 5.0mm measurement is.

The mounting screw length mentioned in another answer is shown on the diagram as 3.5max, so that should rule that out.